# Cannot pass Ruby lambda with ampersand as a block

Tags: ruby, lambda, block

I'm coming back to Ruby after a long time away, and currently struggling with the relationship between blocks and lambdas. I know the general relationship, and I know that in principle you can pass a lambda as a block by prefixing it with an ampersand.

This works for simple examples like:

```rb
(1..5).each &->(n) { n > 0 }
```

But I'm now running into other cases where this doesn't work, such as if I attempt to do this with [PropCheck](https://github.com/Qqwy/ruby-prop_check/):

```rb
PropCheck.forall(integer) &->(n) { n > 0 }
```

results in:

```
(irb):6:in `<main>': undefined method `&' for #<PropCheck::Property:0x00007fd1889af040 @config=#<struct PropCheck::Property::Configuration verbose=false, n_runs=100, max_generate_attempts=10000, max_shrink_steps=10000, max_consecutive_attempts=30>, @hooks=#<PropCheck::Hooks:0x00007fd1889aefc8 @before=#<Proc:0x00007fd1889aef78 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/prop_check-0.14.1/lib/prop_check/hooks.rb:22>, @after=#<Proc:0x00007fd1889aef50 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/prop_check-0.14.1/lib/prop_check/hooks.rb:22>, @around=#<Proc:0x00007fd1889aef28 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/prop_check-0.14.1/lib/prop_check/hooks.rb:22>>, @gen=#<PropCheck::Generator:0x00007fd1889af2c0 @block=#<Proc:0x00007fd1889af270 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/prop_check-0.14.1/lib/prop_check/generators.rb:84>>> (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.3.5/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/irb:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
```

So clearly I'm missing some subtlety about passing lambdas as blocks. Why doesn't this work?  Is there some general thing I'm not aware of that sometimes makes passing lambdas as blocks unacceptable?

Comment: Put it inside the method call parentheses.

Comment: The parens close the argument list so `PropCheck.forall(integer) &->(n) { n > 0 }` is actually interpreted as `PropCheck.forall(integer).&(->(n) { n > 0 })` instead you need to place the lambda inside the argument list e.g. `PropCheck.forall(integer, &->(n) { n > 0 })`. That being said you can likely you can use an implicit block via `PropCheck.forall(integer) {|n|  n > 0 }` instead of using `#to_proc` (`&`)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Sergio and engineersmnky, what was really happening was that I was misunderstanding argument lists of both regular and block parameters. So I can instead do, as suggested:

```
PropCheck.forall(integer, &->(n) { n > 0 })
```

UPDATE: Indeed, I see the second option which seemed to work for me in a quick irb session does not do the right thing (`PropCheck.forall integer &->(n) { n > 0 }`), so the right answer is above.

Comment: @engineersmnky why did you remove that comment? I think it was correct. Even if the second line does not result in a runtime error, it won't produce the desired result (based on testing my mock implementation of `PropCheck.forall`)

Comment: I didn't remove that comment?

Comment: Colin, that was not for you :) Regardless, re-check the second line. As it is now, it can't work.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I did not realize I had removed it. Reporting here: The second one will not work correctly as this will be interpreted as `PropCheck.forall(integer.&(->(n) { n > 0}))`.

Comment: @engineersmnky: unless `integer` is a method, of course. Then the block will bind to that, instead of `forall`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: true I did not consider that the argument to `PropCheck::forall` could be the return value from `integer(&->(n) { n > 0 })` rather than the local variable `integer`